# MFC CListCtrl: insert empty space below last row

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm working on an old MFC application that I have to modify. It has a CListCtrl as central element, filled with multiple rows of data. 
I'd like to draw an icon inside the list control that will be visible if I scroll down below the last row (without inserting a new, empty row, because that messes up the row count and dependencies). For that I need an empty space where I can draw sth. 
The drawing I was arlready able to perform. But I cannot scroll down far enough to see it completely.
I'm totally out of ideas. Any suggestions?

I cannot post code or an image of the original software, so I created a fake app to display my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8S9O.png

The yellow area marks the mentioed area. I want to scroll further down to draw the icon in the space below the last row.

Thanks so far!
B.

Comment: I don't think inserting an "empty space" without it being a legitimate row is possible.  And if it were, I'd question its usefulness.

Comment: If you have control over the height of the CListCtrl you could make it so that the leftover space after drawing the last item is '1 less than the item height'. This will force it to show that as blankness below the last item because the CListCtrl always makes the first visible item align with the top of the control.

Comment: @user1793036: Yes that already works, but it implies that my items in the list never reach the bottom of the app. I have lots of items in the list and always have to scroll down to the last. I want the "empty space" scrollable. But thanks so far.

Comment: have a look at [OnNcCalcSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxb29894.aspx). By adjusting the NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS.rgrc you can tell the framework of the "changed" size of the list